# Maximize window over two displays (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: 18.04, ubuntu-gnome, window-manager, multiple-monitors

I'm using two displays in portrait mode. When I'm using a diff tool (Meld in my case), I want to have the window spread over both displays, such that I see one file version on the left and the other on the right, as in [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLMeR.png). I can drag and resize the window manually, but that's annoying over time.

Is there either a way to make Meld open like this every time, or a keyboard shortcut (or a script that can be assigned one) that does the job?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by doing a *folder* comparison and keeping this open. You manually maximize this across the 2 monitors and then double-click on each difference of interest. Just make sure you close the tab after each file and not the window.

Comment: That's what I usually do, but then I still need to resize every time I start a directory diff.